# Any way to suppress key errors when a dictionary key is not found in Chameleon ZPT templates?

Tags: python, template-tal, chameleon, keyerror

Sometimes it would be nice to be able to do this, just return None in any expression evaluating for a nonexistent dict key instead of raising KeyError.

Comment: Just catch the error with a try/except statement.

Comment: @wwii: This is a *templating language*, not Python.

Comment: Hmm,  my bad, sorry about that. ```get()``` is probably the correct response even if it wasn't a  template language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to access the key instead:

```
<div tal:attributes="class some_dict.get(some_key)">
```

where the `class` attribute would be omitted if `some_key` is not present, as the default return value from `dict.get()` is `None` if the key is missing.